# SQL Server 2008 - UDF Parameter Types And Return Types

Tags: sql-server-2008, parameters, user-defined-functions, table-variable

I often stumble at the following while writing UDFs in SQL 2008. Please tell me whether my following assumptions are right or wrong.

> 1. A UDF can return Data Table.
> 2. But a UDF can't receive a Data Table as a parameter.
> 3. A UDF can receive an User-Defined-Table- Type(UDTT) as a parameter.
> 4. But a UDF can't return an User-Defined-Table-Type(UDTT).

Answer (score 0):

1. Right
2. Right (if you mean - real existing table, not table typed variable)
3. Right
4. Right

Answer (score 0):

1. Right.
2. Right.
3. Right, unless it is a CLR UDF.
4. Right.

Answer (score 0):

1. table valued functions can, no scalar ones
2. Correct
3. Correct
4. Correct